# Cross browser cookie in php. Pass cookies between different browsers

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cookies

I have created an application and I am trying to pass a cookie from one to another application that works in two different ports in apache. (Like application1 in 80 and Application2 in 8080).

That works fine but, when I open the same application in different browsers, the cookie is not being shown in the Application2. Only when I open the application in same browser it is fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Browsers are Independent applications and they keep they are cookies as secure and private as possible.

Answer (score 6):

A cookie is a HTTP header sent from the webserver to the browser. The browser then stores the contents of said header on disk or memory, based on the parameters defined for this cookie. Cookies are not shared between browsers.

[HTTP Cookie on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not shared between browsers. You'd have to rely on database/session id or tools such as this one:

http://www.ts0.com/crosscookie/example.html

Cheers

Comment: when i searched in net i got something as storing as Flash object using the ming.. is it a solution other that using the third party tool.                                                                  2. Session would be risky in my application as one is Php and other is asp.net in different domains.                                                             Please let me know.......

Comment: The tool i linked to is using an swf object, so that would be the same approach.

Comment: this sample is not working in fedora15. Working only in windows.

Comment: That is too bad. Well, worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the cross browser cookies, cookies are set in the specific browser not at the server side.

One thing you can do is IP tracking, means you start storing the IP at your server, and the same call from different browser comes you set the cookie in that browser from server.

Answer (score -1):

You can use session identifier and to store the cookie value on a server.

Application 1/Browser 1 - http://blabla/lele.php?cookieid=euueury576edhdhrtrtrt

Store the cookie info into SQL

```
Cookie id | Cookie info (serialized)
euueury576edhdhrtrtrt | ......
```

Application 1/ Browser 2 - http://blabla/lele.php?cookieid=euueury576edhdhrtrtrt
Here you can extract the cookie information from the server and set it on the new browser.

Using the similar scheme you can update the cookies between browsers also.

Answer (score -2):

Try using server side cookies with few a!! May be it can be of some help